# What happened if the number of Reducer is more than Datanode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I have 3 datanodes, I set the number of Reducer Tasks to 4, what happened in this case? The fourth one will be stand by until one of the datanode finishes its reducer task? Or two of them will be running in the same datanode at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce Tasks do not depend on Datanodes, they depend on the number of slots that are assigned to a particular node. The TaskTracker is responsible for running tasks on these slots on any node in the cluster. You can have more than 1 slot per node, so you can have more than 1 Reduce tasks running per node.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Chaos's answer, if you have set number of reduce task to a number greater than that of the slots present for reduce tasks throughout the cluster, remaining reduce task will run whenever previous reduce slots gets unoccupied.

Comment: Ok,Thank you. But how can I know the number of slots that are assigned to a node?

Comment: @user2597504 If you go to your jobtracker UI (`<jobtrackerAddress>:50030`), you can see the list of nodes and the number of slots on each node